# Interactive Form for math

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

**Background:**
This is my first mini project for Math&Physics Simulation. I know how to `dispatch` a state of `Component` and let them change itself. But I am new to visualization especially with `Javascript`

**Requirements:**
1. They are at least 3 points. `First` and the `last` of time line
2. `numberOfBreakPoints` are changing according to `form`
3. `maximumRuntime` in the line reflex by `form`

Example in the picture

[image: picture]

**Question:**
How to use `Javascript` draw a line like in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using the antd npm module's step component for your such a view.

You can get more information from this [link](https://ant.design/components/steps/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me practice with your given material then I will be back to you. Your answer looks fit to my `ReactJSX`

Comment: Sorry for kept you waiting. I just found that I need to import `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` Otherwise widget will not shown up

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Canvas, that should help you :)

This is the w3schools.com article: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_drawing.asp

Here is some sample code

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#191919";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,5);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try Rohith Murali first. It looks fit with my `React JSX`.